# rsync can't resolve the hostname

Tags: rsync

As my network connection is slow and noisy, I want to use `rsync` to install texlive 2018. I posted a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368478/how-to-cancel-and-resume-texlive-installation) on installation texlive offline in slow an d noisy network.

But, `rsync` is failed in my pc. What is the actual command to do this task?
[Downloading/mirroring the TeX Live repository](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html)

```
  $ rsync -a --delete http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet /home/alhelal/Downloads
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname http: Name or service not known
    rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
    rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs you linked](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html), you should look through the [list of CTAN mirrors](https://ctan.org/mirrors) and find one that supports rsync (*not* http), and plug that into the command:

```
rsync -a --delete rsync://somectan/somepath/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /your/local/dir
```

So, I chose `rsync://tug.ctan.org/CTAN/` as the mirror to use, and your downloads directory as the target. That gives:

```
rsync -a --delete rsync://tug.ctan.org/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /home/alhelal/Downloads
```

AIUI you're in Bangladesh, so you'll probably want to pick a closer one. If you used Shang­hai (rsync://mirrors.shu.edu.cn/CTAN/), the command would be:

```
rsync -a --delete rsync://mirrors.shu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /home/alhelal/Downloads
```

But I tried this (with the tug.ctan.org mirror), and there's a huge problem -- the directory being synced is 3.4 gigs! I suspect you could leave out the archive subdirectory (it's most of the data) with:

```
rsync -a --delete --exclude=/tlnet/archive rsync://mirrors.shu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /home/alhelal/Downloads
```

...but that's still 114MB. According to [this page](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html), the standard installs run from 3 to 19MB depending on platform, so if your connection is slow that's probably going to be a lot better option. The main reason to use `rsync` instead of a web download is that if it fails, you can re-run it and it'll pick up where it left off, so you can just keep running it over and over until it finishes successfully.